# Is it safe to share variables among threads synchronized with atomic loads and stores?

Tags: c, multithreading, gcc, pthreads, atomic

In a C program compiled under GCC in GNU/Linux, is it safe (In the sense that it won't introduce unexpected behavior) to use non-atomic and non-volatile variables for sharing data between threads provided that the threads that use those variables are synchronized by means of atomic loads and stores?. If not, what should I use instead?.

For **instance**, does GCC guarantees that the following code will work as expected (thread_2 always returns 1)?. Assume that both functions are invoked from different threads. Would it be any different if it was written using C11 atomic primitives, if I used POSIX threads mutex to synchronize, or if I used POSIX semaphores?. I include the following code as an specific case only.

```
int data = 0;
int flag = 0;

int thread_1 (void) {
    data = 1;
    __atomic_store_n (&flag, 1, __ATOMIC_RELEASE);
    return -1;
}

int thread_2 (void) {
    while (!__atomic_load_n (&flag, __ATOMIC_ACQUIRE));
    return data;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html GCC allows any integral scalar or pointer type that is 1, 2, 4, or 8 bytes in length. 16-byte integral types are also allowed if ‘__int128’ (see __int128) is supported by the architecture.

Comment: @Snps: Thanks, I just added the missing argument.

Comment: @2501: Thanks you for commenting, however, it doesn't answers my question and is not directly related to it.

Comment: Basically this is what these pseudo-functions are made for. They are the low level implementation of the C11 atomics. The only thing that you should be aware of if you don't use C11, that is you don't qualify your variables as `_Atomic`, nothing protects you from using these variables non-atomically somewhere else in your code. And if you do so, you may have surprising result. So better switch to C11, I think clang and gcc 4.9 implement that now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [GCC Wiki](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Atomic/GCCMM/AtomicSync#Acquire.2BAC8-Release) this should be safe as the **aquire/release** memory model guarantees that the store to `data` in thread 1 will *happen-before* the atomic store to `flag` as `data` is not an atomic variable.

> *"Any store before an atomic operation must be seen in other threads that synchronize."*

Thread 2 will always wait (using [busy waiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting)) until the value of `flag` differs from zero and then return 1.